# Future book trends: a decline in off-topic tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We carried the future, books and the trends tag out of the private beta. I believe we should eradicate them quickly before they grab hold, as they seem to be vehicles for list questions. Currently, I only see one question under books that hasn't been closed. Trends has only one occurrence, that one together with future, which in itself sounds like a pretty meaningless tag. Just try and come up with a wiki description for it and you'll know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Close votes needed:

Not Constructive: [How can I start learning robotics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/512/how-can-i-start-learning-robotics)

Off Topic: [Is there a place for posting "look at what I did" videos?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/502/is-there-a-place-for-posting-look-at-what-i-did-videos)

If we can get them closed, that would solve our problems.

---

Detagging: [Mathematical prerequisites for beginning graduate student in robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/138/mathematical-prerequisites-for-beginning-graduate-student-in-robotics) (done), [Robotics Trends](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/184/robotics-trends) (done)

Answer (score 1):

Once they have been cleansed, can they not be blacklisted?

Questions such as "What book..." have no place on any SE site, and the `books` tag should be blocked.

{edit}

Sometimes, references to books is the ANSWER but should never be the QUESTION

Comment: I'm not sure "What book ..." questions are off topic per se, as books already do come up in answers (e.g. Thrun's "Probabilistic Robotics" has been mentioned [already](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/161/131)). I can imagine a few sensible questions that would ask about a specific book, but I also think the research tag is adequate to cover those

Comment: Tag blacklisting is generally for very serious cases when tags keep popping up. And question input blacklisting is also iffy (false positives/etc). Additionally, we may want to allow some types of Book questions, as long as they are specific to the topic and level (Physics does).